# JavaScript functionality to browser window resize

Tags: javascript, media-queries, responsive-design

I have been writting HTML and CSS for a while but am new to the javascript domain. I am using the below code to control the attributes of a jQuery slider. The code works fine, but what I need to do is change some of the elements within it as the browser screen resizes (or loaded on mobile device) to enable the functionality to work correctly on smaller screens.

```
 $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $(".container").wtListRotator({
                screen_width:534,
                screen_height:300,
                item_width:210,
                item_height:75,
                item_display:4,
                list_align:"left",
                scroll_type:"mouse_move",
                auto_start:true,
                delay:5000,
                transition:"v.slide",
                transition_speed:800,
                easing:"",
                auto_center:true,
                display_playbutton:false,
                display_number:false,
                display_timer: false,
                display_arrow:true,
                display_thumbs:true,
                display_scrollbar:true,
                mouseover_select:false,
                pause_mouseover: true,
                cpanel_mouseover:false,                 
                text_mouseover:false,
                text_effect:"fade",
                text_sync:true,
                cpanel_align:"TR",
                timer_align:"bottom",
                move_one:false,
                auto_adjust:true,
                shuffle:false,
                play_once:false,
                mousewheel_scroll:true,                 
                block_size:75,
                vert_size:50,
                horz_size:50,
                block_delay:35,
                vstripe_delay:90,
                hstripe_delay:180                   
            });
        }
    );
```

I have already implemented media queries on the elements in the CSS so they resize and also across the rest of my site, however I am struggling to change the attributes below when the screen size/re-size event occurs and define this in the above javascript.

```
screen_width:534,
                screen_height:300,
                item_width:210,
                item_height:75,
                item_display:4,
```

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0):

two things that might help you:

1) you can always get the current usable width/height of the browser window using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

2) you can "register" a function to be called whenever the size of the window changes. Examples:

`window.addEventListener("resize",nameOfFunction);`

`window.onresize = function() { //do stuff };`

I'm happy to help if you have further questions...

Comment: Thanks for this, forgive my lack of knowledge, still trying to get to grips with java. If i add the listner to the top of my script and then call the function using 'window.onresize = function() { //do stuff };' , can I add a query to select between either the above function or an alternative for the different screen size?

Comment: you could have the `//do stuff` be something like: `if (window.innerWidth<800) function1(); else function2();` Is that what you mean?